# Working with CSS height property

Tags: css, height

[My website](http://iqhomeautomation.com/iqwordpress/) I'm creating for a company looks great but I just don't know the right CSS to put in the  to make the "WELCOME" title show underneath. I understand that I should put a height, but then if I do that it will show a height for all pages as it is wrapped in an if statement. If on the home page show this widget, if not don't show it. So if I have a set height even if the widget isn't visible on the about page the height will still be in the way. So I thought height:auto; would do it but it's not doing that.

```
#home-services {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    clear: both;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    margin: 0px !important;
}
#home-services section {
    float: left;
    width: 240px;
    height: auto;
    margin-right: 10px;
    background-color: #aaa685 !important;
}
```

[image]
This is what it looks like across all browsers.

What else do I have to put into my CSS to have the WELCOME title move down just on this page? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: where do you want to show 'welcome'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey now add this css

Already add in your css style sheet this css

```
#home-services img{
margin: 0 0 -25px !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
}
```

Now **put this** css  Used this one

```
#home-services .textwidget  img{
margin:0 !important;
}
```

---

Do this

```
 #home-services .textwidget  img{ margin-bottom:25px !important;}
```

Comment: +1 that's definitely what's causing it. Though rather than overriding it, it doesn't seem necessary to have the -25px in the original style

Comment: @Rohit - That kinda worked. It pushed it down to just underneath the div but I still can't push it down anymore, no matter the bottom-margin on the #home-services.  Any suggestions?

Comment: yes you can do this #home-services .textwidget  img{ margin-bottom:25px !important;} and remove margin:0;  i have updated my answer check to  ..........

Comment: Thanks Rohit! I've been able to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Try inserting `padding-top:30px` in the h1 css.

It will clear the problem. If this gets you into trouble with the layout and you need to eliminate the padding, have a javascript function called on load that checks if that h1 is displayed or not and modify the padding accordingly. This is in no way elegant, but it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use jquery in if statement to change CSS like

```
$(".yourclass").css("CSSproperty", "value");
```